# SED - unable to execute some commands on UTF-8 encoded chars

Tags: macos, unicode, utf-8, sed

I got a file that looks like this:

```
<text top="123" left="45" width="50" height="17" font="8">Måndag</text>
```

As noted in the topic, this file is encoded in utf-8. When using this command:

```
cat file | sed 's_.*top="\([0-9][0-9]*\)" left="\([0-9][0-9]*\)".*>\(.*\)<.*_\1 \2 \3_'
```

it never completes the execution and prints nothing.

However executing a line like this one:

```
cat file | sed 's/å/FOO/'
```

gives me a correct output:

```
<text top="123" left="45" width="50" height="17" font="8">MFOOndag</text>
```

Is this a bug in sed or is there something wrong with my regex or the way that I'm using it? What I want is a neat way to extract the top, left and content data without involving too many commands.

Comment: If `sed` doesn't complete on that command, regardless of the input, it looks like a bug. What OS are you running (name, distribution, version)? Do you have the same effect if you run `<file sed …`? What locale are you in? Are you absolutely sure the input is in UTF-8 (post the output of `hd file` or `od -t x1 file`)?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of OS X (10.6.6). Not sure how to check the the locale in bash however `echo $LANG` gives `sv_SE.UTF-8` . I'll probably have to learn another language such as perl suggested by tchrist further down. Till then, I'll work around the problem with an ugly solution.

Comment: Output of `od -t x1 file`:
`0000000    3c  74  65  78  74  20  74  6f  70  3d  22  31  32  33  22  20
0000020    6c  65  66  74  3d  22  34  35  22  20  77  69  64  74  68  3d
0000040    22  35  30  22  20  68  65  69  67  68  74  3d  22  31  37  22
0000060    20  66  6f  6e  74  3d  22  38  22  3e  4d  c3  a5  6e  64  61
0000100    67  3c  2f  74  65  78  74  3e  0a                            
0000111`

Comment: `c3 a5` ⇒ ok, the input is UTF-8. This does look like a bug in OSX's sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this reliably is just to use perl in place of sed:

```
bash$ perl -CSAD -pe 's/foo/bar/g'
```

That will allow Unicode in your arguments, your std streams, and all files you process.

Comment: This problem, as stated above, seems to be a bug in OSX's sed implementation. The "good" solution to this seems to be to learn an alternative language such as perl.

Answer (score 1):

Not all seds are built to handle UTF-8. I would look at the source to see if any relevant patches have been applied. FTR, Red Hat-derived seds *do* handle UTF-8 properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_21.html) suggestion.  Looks like it could work for you.

Comment: [Please don't post just a link as an answer to a question. Summarize the contents of the link for refererence.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) Anyway the input has now been confirmed to be UTF-8.